# Android ImageButton click not working sometimes

Tags: android, onclicklistener, imagebutton

I'm using ImageButton in my xml, like this:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_home"
            android:src="@drawable/home_icon"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="true"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_back"
            android:src="@drawable/back_icon"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="true"
            />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Only one image button is visible at a time.
And I'm capturing the click in my java code as following:

```
  imageButtonHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
        }
    });
```

This works fine sometimes, but not always.
I see this line in my logcat whenever I click on image button:

```
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
```

This line always shows up, even when my ImageButton click action is not performed.

But when my ImageButton click works correctly, this other line adds up to log:

```
 D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
 D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
```

I want my image button to work every time. Please help.

Comment: why are you using framelayout??

Comment: because I need to place these 2 buttons at same position, but need to make only one visible at a time.

Comment: you can use relative layout then

Comment: but I don't think, this is due to frame layout. I'm using ImageButton in other XMLs too, and they are not wrapped in framelayout like this, still they show up same behaviour.

Comment: you have visibility gone for second button. How you gonna see that

Comment: I'm making that visible when needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give some padding to your ImageButtons in order to capture the touch event.

Comment: Yeah but that would make them smaller...I don't want that

Comment: Padding won't make the button smaller. Please try.

Comment: @FebiMathew i had same problem

Answer (score 1):

Use setOnClickListener(...) on the ImageButton

Answer (score -1):

Try to user LinearLayout instead of FrameLayout.

FrameLayout is thought for containing just 1 children.

Answer (score -2):

Replace this and try.

```
imageButtonHome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
    }
});
```